# Как правильно организовать работу в NetBeans нескольким php-разработчикам c общим репозиторием?

Tags: php, git, netbeans

Ситуация: в корпоративной сети c AD на рабочих (только на рабочих!) местах разрешены только Windows. Двум php-разработчикам необходима версионность их кода, тестирование и деплой. Оба работают в NetBeans. Из-за сложностей в политике безопасности в компании невозможно настроить корректную работу инструментов и фреймворков (composer, docker, npm и т.д.) в Windows из-за прокси-сервера с доменной аутентификацией (я в курсе, что это всё работает в Windows, но инструкции НЕ учитывают никакие прокси и прочие ограничения).

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в таком случае нужно выделить сервер (их подключают к внешней сети без прокси) с linux и в NetBeans настроить проект с удалённым кодом, а коммитить можно будет только (и только) с этого сервера? То есть прав ли я, что в инструментах Team в NetBeans невозможно управлять кодом в репозитории на удалённом сервере и следует создавать проекты с удалённым кодом (project with remote code), чтобы видеть вживую минимальные изменения (то есть изменили код, сохранили, код отправился на сервер, обновили страницу в браузере и видим результат), а коммитить только командами, допустим, подключившись через putty?

P.S. нет, cntlm использоваться не будет.

[image: Чтобы было понятнее, о чем я спрашиваю]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

С версионностью проблем как раз меньше всего. Что мешает создать локальный репозиторий Git и комититься там? Если Вы не планируете работать удалённо, то сервер с Git (для push/pull) вполне можно поднять и в локальной сети.

Если же сервер того же Git где-то в облаке, а сами Вы сидите за прокси, который, как Вы говорите, мешает, то вполне возможно придётся поднять дополнительный промежуточный сервер.

А, вот с composer и пр., если действительно мешает прокси, придётся хорошо повозиться. Не исключено, что Вам придётся работать с теми же npm или composer через putty на сервере.